# iOS Swift: How to put an image to the left of a dynamically changed label

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label centered horizontally and an image(an icon) in the view and I want to put the icon always to the left of the label.

The problem is that the label text is changed dynamically and I don't know how to adjust the constraints so that the icon is always to the left of the label.

I did managed to achieve my goal by "CTRL+DRAG" the icon to the label and set the horizontal spacing. But I am getting the "Misplaced view frame" warning.

I am wondering if there's any way to achieve this without getting the misplaced warning?

Comment: can you make a screenshot of your views in the storyboard and one showing the constraints you've set so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Select the table and the image and then in the editor menu select "enclose in view".

Add constraints to center both views vertically in the enclosing view.
Pin the left edge of the icon to the enclosing view. Pin the right edge of the label to the right edge of the view. Add a constraint that sets the desired spacing between the icon and the label.

Add a constraint to center the whole enclosing view in the superview, and another constraint to pin it at the desired vertical position.

### Edit:

I tested this and it works beautifully.

### Edit #2:

I decided to turn my test into a demo project and write a development blog post about it.

You can read the blog post here:

[**A development blog article about centering grouped views, and using the IBInspectable an IBDesignable Xcode settings**](http://wareto.com/ibinspectable-demo).

Answer (score 0):

Try using auto resizing mask for the icon and label.

```
icon.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin)

label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
```